# Trouble with '+' symbol and MySQL REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

so I have a query for a search function like so:

```
    $query1 = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT artistName, artistID, artistTags FROM artists WHERE artistName REGEXP :query  OR artistTags REGEXP :query");
$query1->bindParam(":query", $q);
```

Which works great, but I noticed an issue with an artist name '+44' where it will not return the result. My question is how do I properly escape the + (and other) character to work in the REGEXP function of MySql.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put double backslash before it

```
\\+44
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. Could have sworn I tried that one hundred times, apparently not.